# Matching regex condition

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a string and I would like to replace ##@@##@@ in that string to a carriage return line feed using regex.

I have been trying but haven't had much luck. My expression displays the complete text.

**Expression:** `/^.*(##@@##@@).*$/g`

**String:** This is my name ##@@##@@ ##@@##@@ and identity

Code: str = str.replace(/^.*(##@@##@@).*$/g, '\r\n');

How can I achieve what I am trying to do?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're working too hard. :-) Lose the `^.*` and the `.*$`:

```js
var str = "This is my name ##@@##@@ ##@@##@@ and identity";
str = str.replace(/##@@##@@/g, '\r\n');
console.log(str);
```

`str.replace(/##@@##@@/g, '\r\n')` says "replace the string `##@@##@@` globally in `str` with `\r\n`". In that example you end up with *two* replacements (with a space between) because it occurs two times.

If you want to ignore spaces between occurrences and replace thing slike `##@@##@@ ##@@##@@` with just **one** `\r\n`, then we need to adjust it slightly:

```js
var str = "This is my name ##@@##@@ ##@@##@@ and identity";
str = str.replace(/(?:##@@##@@\s*)+/g, '\r\n');
console.log(str);
```

`.replace(/(?:##@@##@@\s*)+/, '\r\n')` says: "Replace one or more occurrences of `##@@##@@` followed by optional whitespace (`\s` = whitespace, `*` = optional) with `\r\n`." The `(?:...)` groups it together so the `+` ("one or more of the last thing") can be applied to the whole thing. It's a non-capturing group.

Comment: That's superb. I really need to get my Regex skills up-to-date. Is there a space where you trained yourself at regex? If so, I'd love to know :)

Comment: @IK: Glad that helped! I didn't really learn them anywhere in particular or in any kind of organized way. But here are some good resources: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) and http://regex101.com Also, just about anything you see by Steven Levithan on the web about regular expressions is likely to be solid information.